# Applying hasLayout to the i element via zoom or inline-block causes it to line break in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, haslayout

I've had to apply hasLayout to the <i> element to [avoid an IE7 bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186571/background-color-and-italics-sets-off-internet-explorer-7-bug) in which sentences with italics obscured images that those sentences were on the same horizontal line as.

I've done so using either the `zoom` property or the `display: inline-block` property.

But now, any phrase in italics causes the italic portion to behave as if it were it's own block... kinda... or, it just doesn't break or wrap like a normal sentence would, in IE7 only. IE8 and FF work normally.

Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
i {zoom: 1;}
p {font-size: 20px;}
div {width: 200px; border: 2px solid red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<p>Here is a sentence. <i>Here is an italic sentence.</i> Here is another sentence.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Renders like this:

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/968/haslayoutitalics.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/968/haslayoutitalics.png)

How can I get normal functionality back to my *<i>* elements?

Answer (score 1):

You could stack the <img>s above offending <i>s.  The code below removes the hasLayout fix, but stacks the images above the white bars you were seeing before:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>     
<title>Test</title>

<style type="text/css">

img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

p {font-size: 20px; background-color:#FFF;}
div {width: 200px; border: 2px solid red;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" style='float:left;'>
    <p><i>This is an italic sentence.</i></p>
    <p><strong>This is a bold sentence.</strong></p>
    <p>This is a normal sentence.</p>

    <div>
        <p>Here is a sentence. <i>Here is an italic sentence.</i> Here is another sentence.</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```